# Is it possible for a person living in the Kaliyug to perform austerities so as to invoke deities like Lord Brahma or Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, tapasya, devatas

https://www.quora.com/If-I-start-doing-Tapasya-in-this-modern-world-will-lord-Shiva-come-in-front-of-me

This is one answer I saw on Quora.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: @Vivikta Thank you!